# How to open port 8080?

Tags: iptables

I have dav server running on port 8080 and when I try to open over browser it is loading and loading.

OS: Ubuntu server 16.04

Just to test if everyrthing is ok with dav server I have tried to flush with:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

and it is working.

Here is content from my /etc/iptables/rules.v4:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8001 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5666 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8001 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 5666 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

And here is iptables -L output:
[image]

I'm also trying to open 3306 port so external servers can connect but also without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Why is my question vote-down?

Comment: Does anything is listening on port 8080?

Comment: @AlexanderT Yes. You can see that if I flush and accept all in iptables it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in your rules from

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

to

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Because your OUTPUT rules block output packets to non-allowed ports, it's allow only access to port 8080. Change `--dport` to `--sport` fix this issue.

Comment: I have tried and it is not working.

Comment: @CroiOS have you restarted `iptables` after change?

Comment: yes. Here is content of file https://www.dropbox.com/s/1qn7tw1xkw4xd86/Screenshot%202017-06-29%2010.12.42.png?dl=0 and iptables -L. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3naqnpykdd26qpw/Screenshot%202017-06-29%2010.12.06.png?dl=0

Comment: @CroiOS you could execute `iptables-save` to see running rules. Please show it output.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/b6rhkwul79uwsmy/Screenshot%202017-06-29%2011.16.21.png?dl=0

Comment: There is no rule `-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61287/discussion-between-croios-and-alexander-t).

Comment: put back and it works now